# Oracle SQL Developer 4.2 windows authentication for SQL Server

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have SQL developer 4.2 and jtds-1.3.1. I am unable to connect to MS SQL Server
 through Windows Authentication.

1. I have placed the "ntlmauth.dll" and "JtdsXA.dll" in jdk/jre/bin. it's not 
   working.
2. Placing file under jdk/bin is not working.
3. Placing file under Windows/System32 is not working. 
   I restarted the machine every time, while trying above 3 options.

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bit JDK? Make sure the ntlmauth.dll is the same bit level